# HTML and CSS: Place Checkbox in Top Right of an Image

Tags: html, css, checkbox

How do I place a checkbox embedded in the upper right of an image? This currently does not work

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check1" />
</div>
```

Researched this first:

[Placing an image to the top right corner - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282236/placing-an-image-to-the-top-right-corner-css)

Comment: the image is overflowing (add max-width:100%)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the width property of `.container` to `auto`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check1" />
    </div>
```

Comment: accepted answer gave points, feel free to thumbs up question also, tahnks

Answer (score 0):

parent container doesn't need any width. because your `img` width is equal to `500px`. so container can adjust a width automatically

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please add some text to your answer and describe it, please

Comment: parent container does'nt need any width.. because your img width is equal to 500px.   so container can adjust a width automatically..

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Would you please add your description in the answer's body? I will do this for you this time;-). Thank you